Handling Scenarios Where No Elements Are Found After Clicking on a DeckGL Canvas
I'm working on a project where I'm using Cypress for E2E testing on a web application that includes a 3D point cloud rendered with DeckGL's PointCloud layer. The workflow involves clicking on specific points in the canvas, expecting those points to appear in a list afterwards.
Problem
Sometimes, after clicking on the canvas, no points are added to the list, even though the click action seems to be successfully performed. I implemented Cypress recursion to retry the click if the points do not appear in the list, but the issue persists. Strangly this flakyness is only happening in CI tried multiple times running it to reproduce it on local but didnt got any luck, till now its only happening in CI
Here's a simplified version of my code:
const hoverAndClickPoint = (canvasSelector, point) => {
    cy.get(canvasSelector)
        .trigger("mousemove", { clientX: point.x, clientY: point.y, force: true })
        .wait(500) // This wait is sometimes necessary but also flagged by ESLint
        .click(point.x, point.y, { force: true });
};

cy.recurse(
    () => cy.get('.pointListContainer hds-list-item').its("length"),
    (length) => length > 0, 
    {
        log: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        delay: 1000,
    }
);


I have already raise a discussion cypress-recurse repo #326. Please check this for more info.
I tried using cypress-recurse plugin to click on points recursively. However, I feel still I am missing something. I want whatever point click is happening that behviour same should be there in CI. Quite interested in solving this.

The use of recurse() does not seem correct. Shouldn't you be repeating the click inside the recurse iteration? It's unclear if the trigger() and/or click() are not working first time, or the app is just slow to respond. The CI factor would suggest the latter since CI can be slower - in that case you don't need recurse, you just need a longer timeout.

I would try substituting events from cypress-real-events if increasing the timeout has no effect.

@Rubio I tried multiple things, as you suggested on your first and 2nd comment. Even cypress-real-events was not helpful. Main problem is point click is failing in CI and the fact that things are working on local without recurse and trigger, I tried multiple things to see whether click is happening but still no help and in CI its failing

Using force:true option turns off action-ability checks, which are to make sure the element is ready for the click action you want to test. So it is a bad strategy to use, probably is causing the flakiness. What happens when you remove both force options?

@D.Zamprogna Initially I tried without force:true. However, In order to resolve this CI click issue, I tried with force. Without removing and keeping it is not making any difference.

I have no clue why this same click on the points are not showing. I even tried to first hover the element then tried clicking by grabbing that hovered element. Still facing the same issue. I mean in CI the same click is not working. Should I checking anything else before the clicking? The fact that things are working in the local and not working in CI is making me annoyed, at least I would have agreed if the issue would have been greater than click is not happening in CI

Some of the code you use is quite wacky, I would delete all the failed attempts like recurse and forced-click as they do nothing and just cloud the issue. I would also suggest the .trigger can be removed since you already have coordinates in the click, what's the point of moving first? Try adding the source for the component as it's very likely the issue is inside the react code.

@Hemsworth.H I have made the test code more simpler now its just clicking within the dom element without force and trigger. Still things are working in local and same point click is failing in CI. I am afraid, I didn't understood your point for "Try adding the source for the component ..." ?
